# Whats wrong in this SpingMVC and Hibernate transaction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am creating a small application that manages two entities using hibernate and springMVC, one called `User` and the other one is `Application`. The problem is that when I try to enter values ​​in the database (MySQL) I get the following error:
`org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread.`
Despite this error I have the necessary notes to make transactions, but it still does not work. Here I leave the code:
SpringConfig:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.app")
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
    }
}
```

Hiberate Config:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "com.test.app"
})
public class HibernateConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.esliceu.examen.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
    }

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
    }

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
    }

@Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

AppController:

```
import com.test.app.model.Application;
import com.test.app.service.ApplicacionService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
@Transactional
public class AplicacioController {
@Autowired
private AplicationService aplicationService;

@GetMapping("/applications")
private String testInsert(){
    Application app = new Aplicacio();
    app.setId(1);
    app.setName("fooApp");
    aplicacioService.insertOrUpdate(app);
    return "applications";
    }
}
```

ApplicationDao:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class AplicacioDao  implements AppDao{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
@Override
public void insertOrUpdate(Aplication app) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(app);
    }
}
```

Application Model:

```
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "aplication")
@Audited
public class Aplicacio {
@Id
@Column(name = "idApp")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "applications")
private List<User> ysers;

//...contructor, geters ands setters//
}
```

And this is the service layer:

```
package com.test.app.service;

import com.test.app.dao.ApplicationDao;
import com.test.app.model.Aplicacio;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ApplicationService implements AppService{
@Autowired
private AplicacioDao applicationDao;

public List<Application> findAll(){
    return applicationDao.findAll();
    }

@Override
public List<Application> findAllDatabase() {
    return applicationDao.findAllDataBase();
    }

@Override
public Application findById(int id) {
    return applicationDao.findById(id);
    }

@Override
public void insertOrUpdate(Application app) {
    applicationDao.insertOrUpdate(app);
    }

@Override
public void delete(Application app) {
    applicationDao.delete(app);
    }
}
```

I am configuring everything through annotations as you can see, but I am unable to see where the error is. If someone could tell me where the error is, I would be very grateful

Comment: Please put the code of `aplicacioService` for the solution. The problem may lie in service layer.

Comment: petition done @AnishB.

Comment: Thanks :)  Please check the updated answer for service layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for service layer by removing `@Transactional` from DAO and Controller :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ApplicationService implements AppService{
@Autowired
private AplicacioDao applicationDao;

public List<Application> findAll(){
    return applicationDao.findAll();
    }

@Override
public List<Application> findAllDatabase() {
    return applicationDao.findAllDataBase();
    }

@Override
public Application findById(int id) {
    return applicationDao.findById(id);
    }

@Override
public void insertOrUpdate(Application app) {
    applicationDao.insertOrUpdate(app);
    }

@Override
public void delete(Application app) {
    applicationDao.delete(app);
    }
}
```

Or problem is with `HibernateConfig` class, plz check that.

Comment: I tried but that's dont work, and well i think its better if I set ``@Transactional`` on the controller, because is the controllor who starts the transaction

Comment: But it's not a correct way. Try in the service layer, it should work. Further check for unwanted transactions close.

Comment: Generally speaking, the service (or parts of it) would normally be Transactional, and not the Controller or DAO. Didn't adding Transactional to the service and removing it from the others help?

Comment: @IdoSalomon Exactly.

Comment: @J.Doe Then, check HibernateConfig class properly. Problem may exist in the config.

Comment: Ok, you're right and I had another error in other class 
which had nothing to do with the previous error. Thx!!